# Update VueJs component on route change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way to re-render a component on route change? I'm using Vue Router 2.3.0, and I'm using the same component in multiple routes. It works fine the first time or if I navigate to a route that doesn't use the component and then go to one that does. I'm passing what's different in props like so

```
{
  name: 'MainMap',
  path: '/',
  props: {
    dataFile: 'all_resv.csv',
    mapFile: 'contig_us.geo.json',
    mapType: 'us'
  },
  folder: true,
  component: Map
},
{
  name: 'Arizona',
  path: '/arizona',
  props: {
    dataFile: 'az.csv',
    mapFile: 'az.counties.json',
    mapType: 'state'
  },
  folder: true,
  component: Map
}
```

Then I'm using the props to load a new map and new data, but the map stays the same as when it first loaded. I'm not sure what's going on.

The component looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    loading: true,
    load: ''
  }
},

props: ['dataFile', 'mapFile', 'mapType'],

watch: {
    load: function() {
        this.mounted();
    }
},

mounted() {
  let _this = this;
  let svg = d3.select(this.$el);

  d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, `static/data/maps/${this.mapFile}`)
    .defer(d3.csv, `static/data/stations/${this.dataFile}`)
    .await(function(error, map, stations) {
    // Build Map here
  });
}
```

Comment: Show the component?

Comment: Also, what router version?

Comment: @BertEvans I've updated the question with the component and vue router version. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The alternate solution to this question handles this situation in more cases.**

First, you shouldn't really call `mounted()` yourself. Abstract the things you are doing in `mounted` into a method that you can call from `mounted`. Second, Vue will try to re-use components when it can, so your main issue is likely that `mounted` is only ever fired once. Instead, you might try using the `updated` or `beforeUpdate` [lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) event.

```
const Map = {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      load: ''
    }
  },
  props: ['dataFile', 'mapFile', 'mapType'],
  methods:{
    drawMap(){
        console.log("do a bunch a d3 stuff")
    }
  },
  updated(){
    console.log('updated')
    this.drawMap()
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
    this.drawMap()
  }
}
```

Here's a [little example](https://jsfiddle.net/p2c3b10t/1/), not drawing the d3 stuff, but showing how `mounted` and `updated` are fired when you swap routes. Pop open the console, and you will see `mounted` is only ever fired once.

Comment: but when use mounted and updated with together, and have axios http request, it will send request repeatly. (sorry for eng)

Comment: I agree with @FarshidRezaei above: If you put an http request in `updated()` surely the returned data from that request will change (or update) the component data which will trigger `updated()` again and cause an infinite loop.

Comment: So what's the solution ? I have the same problem with axios

Comment: @qwertzuiop The answer below. Is a better solution to this issue. I would delete this answer, but it's accepted and I can't at the moment.

Answer (score 96):

You may want to add a :key attribute to `<router-view>` like so:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

This way, Vue Router will reload the component once the path changes. Without the key, it won’t even notice that something has changed because the same component is being used (in your case, the Map component).

Comment: This would work, but can be quite inefficient. Say you move a map and change the URL to the gps coords... this would refresh the entire component, every time.

Comment: Is there a github issue corresponding to this problem?

Comment: simple solution, perfect

Comment: I hate that this is the best answer, but this is a pretty good answer, aside from the drawbacks mentioned by @RayFoss.

Comment: In my case I do truly navigate between two different instances of the component `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, so I need to actually refresh the entire component. So thank you.

Comment: this solution does not works properly, when you need to manage child routes. There is my approach for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806432/1330193

Answer (score 22):

## **UPDATE --- 3 July, 2019**

I found this thing on `vue-router` documentation, it's called [In Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). By the description of it, it really suits your needs (and mine actually). So the codes should be something like this.

```
export default () {
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // called when the route that renders this component has changed,
    // but this component is reused in the new route.
    // For example, for a route with dynamic params `/foo/:id`, when we
    // navigate between `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, the same `Foo` component instance
    // will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens.
    // has access to `this` component instance.
    
    const id = to.params.id
    this.AJAXRequest(id)
    next()
  },
}
```

As you can see, I just add a `next()` function. Hope this helps you! Good luck!

---

**Below is my older answer.**
Only saved for the purpose of "progress"

My solution to this problem was to watch the `$route` property.
Which will ended up you getting two values, that is `to` and `from`.

```
watch: {
  '$route'(to, from) {
    const id = to.params.id
    this.AJAXRequest(id)
  }
},
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work, I assume because I've changed the routing configuration and use the vue-cli-plugin-ssr . I can access the beforeEach hook in the routing configuration. Is there a way I can target my component specifically and change one of its data() properties?

Comment: Hello @SearchingSolutions. Hm.. I have never used `vue-cli-plugin-ssr` yet,  I think you should create new question instead. Because your case might be different than the current question but similiar. I also didn't found anything about `beforeRouteUpdate` and the plugin you're using (but that's because I only take a quick look).

Comment: This way is much better than the `key` hacky way.

Comment: Yes @AbdallaArbab, the `key` hacky way will actually trigger the whole lifecycle hook rendering the whole children every time the `$route.fullPath` this includes changes such as query string and changes in dynamic value. Checkout about the official docs about [key](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) to know more.

Comment: Best answer, much better that the inefficient "key" method sent in <router-view /> Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the old solution, it's good for having access `to, from` values

Answer (score 2):

you can use just this code:

```
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem and solved by following way;

**ProductDetails.vue**

```
 data() {
    return {
       ...
       productId: this.$route.params.productId,
       ...
     };
   },
 methods: {
  ...mapActions("products", ["fetchProduct"]),
  ...
 },
created() {
    this.fetchProduct(this.productId);
...
}
```

The `fetchProduct` function comes from `Vuex` store. When an another product is clicked, the route param is changed by `productId` but `component` is not re-rendered because `created` life cycle hook executes at initialization stage.

When I added just key on `router-view` on parent component `app.vue` file

**app.vue**

```
<router-view :key="this.$route.path"></router-view>
```

Now it works well for me. Hopefully this will help Vue developers!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but slightly different. I just added a watch on the prop and then re-initiated the fetch method on the prop change.

```js
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import Page  from './content/Page.vue';
import Post  from './content/Post.vue';

const props = defineProps({ pageSlug: String });
const pageData = ref(false);
const pageBodyClass = ref('');

function getPostContent() {
    let postRestEndPoint = '/wp-json/vuepress/v1/post/' + props.pageSlug;
    fetch(postRestEndPoint, { method: 'GET', credentials: 'same-origin' })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            pageData.value = res;
            
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
getPostContent();

watch(props, (curVal, oldVal) => {
    getPostContent();
});
watch(pageData, (newVal, oldVal) => { 
    if (newVal.hasOwnProperty('data') === true && newVal.data.status === 404) {
        pageData.value = false;
        window.location.href = "/404";
    }

    
    
});
```

**router - index.js**

```js
       {
            path: "/:pageSlug",
            name: "Page",
            component: Page,
            props: true,
        },
        {
            path: "/product/:productSlug",
            name: "Product",
            component: Product,
        },
        {
            path: "/404",
            name: "404",
            component: Error404,
        }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33221659)