# VueJS Memory Leak when Switching Routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks, vue-router, vuex

Whenever I switch routes, I have noticed that Vue components in my application are never destroyed and only created (the # Deleted column is always 0 as I toggle between routes). To be extra clear, the number of new components created is always equal to the number of components displayed on that route i.e. NONE of the Vue components are ever destroyed and every component on the route is recreated when a route is revisited.

[image]

I've been researching to debug the problem and I know that the following are usually culprits of memory leaks in VueJS.

- The use of a Global Event Bus and failure to unregister the callback. [This is detailed clearly here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1181). While I do use a Global Event Bus in some areas of my application, I'm also experiencing memory leaks on pages where I don't create any event listeners on the Global Event Bus, which leads me to believe that this is not the issue here.
- Failure to manually clean up memory yourself when using 3rd party libraries, a problem outlined by the [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). Again, I've been looking at memory usage on pages that do not use third party libraries and I'm still getting memory leaks on those.

There is one more potential issue I've come across which I don't quite understand. In this [github thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7101), the OP said the following in regards to potential causes of memory leaks in VueJS:

> So I made sure I wasn't doing anything stupid like storing a reference
> to this on a Vuex Store...

**Can someone please explain what the OP means here in regards to Vuex and memory leaks?**

**Additionally, what are some other potential issues that cause memory leaks in VueJS that I have missed that could be affecting my application?**

**How else should I be debugging my memory leak outside of using the Memory tab in Chrome devtools?**

Comment: We're having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: I haven't exactly solved all my issues but I posted this question in the Vue forum as well and a VueJS core team member helped to partially answer my question: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-memory-leak-when-switching-routes/38865

Comment: Hmm, chartjs must be destroyed. Okay, in my case, I've removed every 3rd party plugin. Still the same. On every route changed, whole lotta VueComponent is added to the dom/but no one is deleted. A quick fix for that is using transition+keep-alive on router-view,  which surprised me how low memory it uses. I'm still inspecting why those components cannot be deleted.

Comment: Have you made sure you're cleaning up your global event bus listeners (I'm assuming you're using them) in your components? Cleaning those up helped vue properly destroy components. More info here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1181

Comment: Yeah, that didn't solve my problem. I've also invoked .$destroy() for those eventBus, on destroyed, but no affect. This thing is so hard to track.

Comment: @TunaYagci make sure you're cleaning up after any setIntervals as well. More info within the answer to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424507/vue-router-creates-always-a-new-component-instance

Comment: Yes, I've also seen that one. I think we can create a vue-leakage plugin, as those guys did for nodejs: https://github.com/andywer/leakage I just need to find out which components exactly didn't get destroyed on route change. It's hard to track heap snapshot in a very large app. Just to make sure, you are tracking heap snapshots, creating 2 snapshots and comparing them, right? When I compare those on route change, no Vue component is deleted, but many added.

Comment: @TunaYagci that sounds like a good idea. Regarding tracking heap snapshots, that's exactly what I did and I agree that it's such a pain to track in a large app. I guess now I know this is something to incrementally check on when building something from scratch again.

Comment: One big problem on creating that kind a plugin is that, we cannot manually GC in a plugin AFAIK, hence we cannot detect if component is deleted or not.

Answer (score 1):

Memory is such a pain to debug and your logs look curiously similar to mine.

What i found was be careful of your logs :
console.log(vuecompoent) actually stores your component in memory and does not release it.

Also consider that I turned off vue dev tools as well, but im not sure if this was causing the issue .

Look into the retainers section . This may give you some insight.