# Find Vue Components Not Being Destroyed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory, vuejs2

If I load my app and take a Chrome memory heap snapshot straight away, I get the following results.

[image]

If I click around my web app and then return to the original page loaded, and take another memory heap snapshot I get the following results.

[image]

From this, we can see there are now ~10x the number of VueComponents and an increase in the number of Vue instances.

This is having a big impact on memory usage of the app.

What tools/methods are available to track down the culprit components that are not being destroyed?

Comment: How did you filter on VueComponent in Chrome's memory heap snpashot ? Interesting question anyways

Comment: @Toodoo Developer console -> Memory -> Take Snapshot -> Class Filter -> "Vue"

Comment: Are you using [History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I did that, but when I  type "Vue" nothing cames out, that's why I'm asking. Will lookingforward, thanks for answer

Comment: @Toodoo depending on your setup, your class names might be changed/obfuscated when you compile your code for production, and that's why you can't find anything for "Vue". Try compiling it for a development environment instead.

Comment: @Toodoo, as mentioned in the comment above the filtering only worked for us when compiling for development.

Comment: @Delena, we are using hash mode for development (where the snapshot above was taken) and when used in our electron app. In the browser, we use history mode for production.

Comment: @Josh I first thought history mode might use more memory, but it turns out it doesn't. This issue sounds non-trivial. There are a few related Github issues and StackOverflow questions, but none of them have conclusive answers. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2384, https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2389, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400373/vuejs-memory-leak-when-switching-routes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424507/vue-router-creates-always-a-new-component-instance/49424657#49424657 . Perhaps you can add your example to one of the github issues.

Comment: The newest version of the [vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) has a performance section that might be helpful (I haven't tried it yet). I've used this tool as well: https://github.com/vue-perf-devtool/vue-perf-devtool

Comment: @Josh If you're using `transition` and `keep-alive`, there's a known [memory leak issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9842) reported recently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't think the above really apply to our situation. The issue is that there are endless possible causes, which is why it would be really useful to have a tool to find which components are problems to narrow down the search :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tracking Down Orphaned Vue Components

As the question suggested, I was pretty sure these memory issues were caused by orphaned Vue components that were not being cleaned. It is possible to look through the source for circular references etc... and fix manually.

I was looking for a way to find the specific Vue components so I could narrow my search in the code.

## Using Heap Snapshot

The best method I have found does require some manual effort but works pretty well.

From the Chrome dev tools Heap snapshot we can search for detached

> N.B. You must compile Vue for dev, not production, or this will not work

[image: how to search for detached nodes]

This will show a list of elements that have been detached from the DOM.

We can now click on one of these items to highlight it.

[image: selecting a detached element]

Then we can head over to the Chrome dev tools console and type `$0` to get the element.

[image: showing selected element in console]

From this I can see that the email input from my login page is the culprit and so I should investigate why this is not being destroyed.

## Conclusion

While this does provide a good way to track down components that are not being destroyed, please note that not all `detached` nodes are bad, apply the context of your app to decide whether it is a memory leak or not.