# How to make pagination and content render on browser back button in Vue cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I am trying to make in Vue.js CLI table with pagination and pages I have API backend and everything.
Now I have URL with "?page=1" and I want when I click on browser back button my table and pagination render on the same page what is URL. Right now on browser back button only URL change but the content stays the same.
But I hear there is a global fix with Vue router for that does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: This problem is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461882/update-vuejs-component-on-route-change/55999879#55999879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are talking about, but in [this vue school video](https://vueschool.io/lessons/how-to-rerender-components-when-vue-router-params-changes) they talk about the Vue Router not always picking up on changes if the same component is being used. You can handle it by adding a key to the router-view with value **$route.path**. Then any change to the path will trigger a reload of the component.

Comment: I found how to do it i just need to add to router-view :key="this.$route.fullPath" and that fix my problem with browser back

Answer (score 0):

You could put a watcher on the route:

```
computed : {
  page () {
    return this.$route.params.page
  }
},
watch : {
  page (val) {
    updateContent(val)
  } 
},
mounted () {
  updateContent(this.page)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know for watch but there is global fix with vue-router but I dont know how to do that...