# Vue-router is changing the url but not re-rendering the component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

First of all I've checked and history mode is turned on, I invoke `vue-router` like so:

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: routes,
});
```

The current route I am on is `/page/item/8`, and I am redirecting to `/page/item/9`. Currently the url changes but the page does not re-render leaving me on the same view I had before.

This redirection is done like so:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'PageItem', params: { itemId: '9' }}).catch(err => {
  // Stop Vue.router throwing an error if a user clicks on a notification with the same route.
  if (err.name !== 'NavigationDuplicated') {
    this.$logger.debug.log(err);
  }
});
```

The route in question like so:

```js
import PageWrapper from '@/layouts/PageWrapper';
    
export default [
  {
    path: '/page',
    name: 'page',
    component: PageWrapper,
    children: [
      ... Other Routes ...
      {
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "page-item" */'@/pages/PageItem'),
        name:      'PageItem',
        path:      '/item/:itemId/:view?',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Any ideas, I've tweaked the code to remove identifying code so apologies if it looks a bit odd.

Comment: please take a look on this: https://mokkapps.de/vue-tips/re-rendering-vue-routes-when-path-parameters-change

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only the `itemId` route param is changing. In this situation, since the same route components are being used before and after the transition, vue-router will reuse the existing route components; they don't get destroyed and recreated. So if you're loading data in the component `created` or `mounted` hooks then they won't be called again after the route changes. Instead you need to use  [`beforeRouteUpdate`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) or watch `$route` for changes.

If you want to force the component to be destroyed and recreated (not recommended) then you need to `key` the `<router-view>` on the route:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">
```

Read the [Data Fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html) guide for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a week trying to figure out why my UI wouldn't work and then found this.

Comment: I've tried both those approaches, and my data is like one "url request" behind. Ie. The url changes on first change, no change in the component, then I go to the next one, and it updates - but it's the last URL data.

Answer (score 2):

This solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638787/1330193 not works well in all situations, because it will redraw full components tree, and rebuild all components context. It means, that every time when you change `:view` parameter, you will make an additional API request for item with `:itemId`.

For example, if you want to save scope of parent route (in your case: `/page/item/:itemId`) and only child routes should to be redrawn (in your case: `/page/item/:itemId/:view?`), you can use this solution:

1. specify, which param you want to watch inside routes config:

```
import PageWrapper from '@/layouts/PageWrapper';
    
export default [
  {
    path: '/page',
    name: 'page',
    component: PageWrapper,
    children: [
      ... Other Routes ...
      {
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "page-item" */'@/pages/PageItem'),
        name:      'PageItem',
        path:      '/item/:itemId/:view?',
        meta: {
          watchParam: 'itemId' //
        }
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

2. Put it in your layout component:

```
<router-view :key="$route.params[$route.meta.watchParam]">
```

So with that, router will re-render route's component only when `itemId` parameter changed.

Anyway, it's more declarative way to do that than watch component's props.
In my opinion, it is a common behaviour, and should be implemented in vue-router library in more native way.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works well, but all child component is reloaded. So if you use a `:key` on the `<router-view>` on the main component, it may be too overkill if you have other routes like `/xxx/:id` and don't want to reload them.

The ideal solution would be to watch parameter change, then re-initialize state from this. But in some components, handling this logic makes it too complicated (i.e if there is a lot of variables or refs to re-initialize).

So what I did is to wrap my component I want to reset in a component, and the `:key` only on this wrapper.

I have a `ReloadOnRouteChange.vue` component with only:

```html
<template>
    <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
</template>
```

And in my router, I wrap my component:

```js
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
        name: 'user',
        path: '/users/:id',
        component: User,
    },
```

like this:

```js
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
+       path: '/',
+       component: ReloadOnRouteChange,
+       children: [
+           {
                name: 'user',
                path: '/users/:id',
                component: User,
+           },
+       ],
    },
```

This way, only the `User` component will be fully reloaded when only the id change in the route.