# router-link is not working when used in loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-router

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <router-link
      v-for="categoryName in allCategory"
      :key="`${categoryName.which_category}`"
      class="dropdown-item capitalized"
      :class="{ active: activeLink === categoryName.which_category }"
      :to="`/category/${categoryName.which_category}`"
      >{{ categoryName.which_category }}
    </router-link>
  </div>
</li>
```

I am using Vue 3. The problem that is occurring here is that when I click any of the links, it works the first time, and it goes to the expected page. When I click next time, it does not work, it just changes the route (url) but it does not go to the expected page. It stays on the same previous page. Can anybody give me any solutions for this? Thank you.

Comment: I think it is the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638667/vue-router-is-changing-the-url-but-not-re-rendering-the-component